# JOIN Two tables one of which has where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to join two tables where Person table fields(having Street S1) will be merged into Student table, but adding new field (STUDENT/NONSTUDENT).
Student table has 1milyon rows, Result person table has max 100 rows. 
What is the best sql for performance to merge them all?

```
student table (name, age)
A-12
B-23
C-24

person table (name, street, live)
A-S1-L
B-S2-NL
D-S1-L
```

At the end I want such result

```
A-12-Student
D-NULL-NOTSTUDENT
```

Comment: Will the student status change frequently or be depended on by an application to be always up to date? A case statement may be the way to either update this table or create a view that has a calculated column for `STUDENT/NONSTUDENT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select p.name,
       s.age, 
       case when s.name is null then 'NotStudent' 
             else 'Student' end as IsStudent
from person p
left join student s on p.name = s.name
where p.Street = 's1'
```